# Consolidated Access Request Page/Settings

Tags: access-requests

I've recently become a SP2013 site collection admin in order to back-fill a co-worker, and we are trying to find a way to ensure that the Access Requests are sent to my email now instead of hers. I've been hunting through the last few days and the only place I can see to adjust the value is "Site Settings > Permissions > Access Request Settings", but that is for the specific site I'm looking at currently.

We have around 144 sites (a majority of those are sub-sites) in our collection, and while most of them are inheriting their permissions (which appears to remove the page for access request) we do have a bunch with unique permissions.

Is there any way to consolidate the settings for who the access request goes to, and to see all pending requests across multiple sites/sub-sites?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a shared mailbox for access requests. There is no 'global' view of access requests, though. You'd have to build a custom solution that aggregated all of the lists (/siteUrl/Access Requests) together.